# Add view to subView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, addsubview

I implemented [core plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) in `xcode`. I'm trying to insert the legend in another `cell`. Here is my code of how I implemented the `legend`.

```
- (void)configureLegend
{
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    CPTLegend *theLegend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];

    // Configure the legend
    theLegend.numberOfColumns = 1;
    theLegend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
    theLegend.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    theLegend.cornerRadius = 5.0;

    // Add legend to graph
    graph.legend = theLegend;
    graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorRight;
    CGFloat legendPadding = - (self.chartView.bounds.size.width / 8);
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(legendPadding, 0.0);
```

Here is what I tried:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
    [cell addSubview:theLegend];
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'CPTGraph *' to parameter of type 'UIView *'
```

I understand the error, and what I did wrong. My question is, how can I add the `legend` as a `subview` of a cell?

**Edit**

Here is what I'm talking about:

[image]

I want to move the part that has all the info - "AAPL" GOOG" "MSFT" (the thing on the right), to another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you're trying to add an object that isn't of type `UIView` as a subview to the cell. Add the CTPGraph object to an instance of type `CPTGraphHostingView`, then add this as a subview to the cell:

```
CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

[cell addSubview:hostingView];
```

Furthermore, you shouldn't really be accessing cells like that. You should be adding the graph as a subview from UITableView's delegate method, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Use this method to retrieve the legend and add it to the cell before returning the completed cell.

**Updated** - You're using a static UITableView, so the implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` differs slightly. You have to retrieve the cell from `super` (the Table View) instead of dequeuing a reusable cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    ...retrieve instance of graph...

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

    [cell addSubview:hostingView];

    return cell;
}
```

**Update 2** - To add only the legend to the cell:

```
[cell.layer addSublayer:graph.legend];
```

**Update 3** - Your text could be upside down because the coordinate system used by the legend's layer may be different. You can fix this by rotating the layer 180 degrees using a transform:

```
legendLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI / 180.0f, 0, 1, 0);
```

Comment: I'm using a static `tableView`. Should I still call `cellForRow`?

Comment: Yep. The implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` changes a bit in the instance of a static UITableView. You retrieve your cell from `super` rather than dequeuing a reusable cell:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ... configure cell ...
    return cell;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I just tried it, and it adds the whole chart the that cell. I'm asking how to just add the legend, the part that has the names and color of everything

Comment: I've updated my answer. For any subsequent comments you have, I'll keep updating the answer to try and help you out rather than commenting a bunch of times.

Comment: It now added it to the cell, but the text is upside down. (When I take remove  the `addSublayer` it's right side up.) Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76400/discussion-between-john-rogers-and-horray).

Answer (score 0):

use

> CPTGraphHostingView

to place inside UIView,

Answer (score 0):

Because `CPTGraph` * isn't a subclass of `UIView *`. You need to add the `CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView` to your view by doing `[cell addSubview:graph.hostingView]`;